# Joomla 2.5 Ajax saving data to db character encoding

Tags: ajax, joomla, character-encoding

I try to send a datetime ( 2013-03-12 09:43:09 ) string from a form via ajax to the db. I used follwoing JS

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
    data: { 
    end: $('#endtime').val()
    },
    url: 'index.php?option=com_sprojectfree&view=checkin&task=saveSlot&format=raw',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

The url points to the method saveSlot in my controller.php

```
public function saveSlot ()
{
    $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $data = new stdClass();
    $data->end = $input->get('end');
    db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $result = $db->insertObject( '#__spf_chunks', $data, 'id' );
...
}
```

The data objects look like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [end] => 2013-03-12095730
)
```

and the POST source like this:

```
end=2013-03-12+09%3A57%3A30
```

I tried all combinations of charactersets, urldecode() and encodeURIComponent() in JS but nothing gives me the correct string with : back to save it in the db. What could I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
echo urldecode("2013-03-12+09%3A57%3A30");
```

the decoding in php side.

Also normally when you call ajax the content type is no need mention.

Instead of passing data as object you can pass like this

```
var data = "end="+$('#endtime').val();
data: encodeURIComponent (data)
```

In controller you can access via `JRequest::getVar('end');`

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried this before and it doesn't works. urldecode($data->end) gives me 2013-03-12101707 The error must be at another place.

Comment: try to assign $data->end to a variable then decode. Bcoz its working fine urldecode("2013-03-12+09%3A57%3A30");. Also try instead of object send as params.It may work

Comment: Using urldecode(JRequest::getVar('end')) works fine, BUT it is deprecated. Using JInput:: is recommended. Using my code above gives me something like that: 2013-03-1220103A433A33. The goal is to use the input filter: `$data->end = urldecode($input->get('end','','string'));`  and it works